Could not create a new view issue
I need to create a WPF application to implement mirror casting.
Refer to Microsoft official sample: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/Projection/cs
But it is UWP application. So I was trying to convert it to WPF application, this is my git repo: https://github.com/tomxue/MirrorCastDemo
The main change might be some UI parts and I used a MainWindow (Window) instead of MainPage (Page). Note: I tried to use a MainPage (Page) to follow UWP sample but got the same error.
When running my WPF application, I got below error message: "Could not create a new view because the main window has not yet been created"

It is very confusing. I don't understand what the "main window" in the error message means.
This function StartProjecting() belongs to Scenario3.xaml.cs. And we navigate to Scenario3 page by clicking button on MainWindow. So MainWindow was already created.
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Scenario3 scenario3 = new Scenario3();
    ScenarioFrame.Navigate(scenario3);
}

Any idea?

In gereral, CoreWindow is closely tied to UWP and I don't think it can be used in other platform.

Thank you for your reply! If I wrap those UWP projection functions in a UWP Class Library and then call them from WPF application, would that work? @emoacht

I doubt it. You should check Windows Runtime APIs not supported in desktop apps first.
